# Error in getting the access token using authorization code using oauth for Google

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build an application that would fetch the events from a user's Google calendar. Once I get the authorization code which the user is given and asked to enter in another page, I try to exchange it for access_token. But I get an error in the post request I am sending to retrieve the token.

```
client_id=encodeURIComponent("id.apps.googleusercontent.com");
client_secret=encodeURIComponent("secret.apps.googleusercontent.com");
$.post("http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token/code="+auth_code
                +"&client_id="+client_id+"&client_secret="+client_secret
                +"&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code",
        function(response){
            console.log('Response = '+ response);
        }
);
```

Can someone tell me the error in the post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the response coming back for the error reason.  This appears to be jQuery code, so you could look under the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools (View, Developer, Developer Tools, Network) to see the HTTP response.

That said, unless you're using jQuery in a server-side environment, you're using the wrong OAuth flow.  You should be using the implicit/javascript flow, where you don't need to get an authorization code or exchange it-- you immediately get an access token returned in the hash fragment of your URL:

**[OAuth2UserAgent](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent)**

Please clarify your question more with language/environment/objective.

Comment: My application is supposed to work in a smart tv. I wanted to fetch the user's events from Google calendar and create an alarm for them.